# SSIS control flow Precedence Constraint Editor Failure Value package executed failure despite completing the desired path code

Tags: ssis

I have two code pieces.
One is an execute process task which connects to an ftp using winscp scripting.
In the code there will be

```
get file.txt
```

Now if the file isn't there it should fail which is expected.
I added in a failure precedence constraint Editor which leads to another script task to move files around based on this failure.
That piece of the code succeeds.

But the problem is that despite this the package execution completed but with error.
Is there a way to change that to package execution completed successfully?

The goal is that just because a file isn't there in an ftp site and the script task fail it shouldn't fail the entire package for that one particular error.

However I cannot use changing the failtaskifreturncodeisnotsuccessvalue because a potential error could be that the ftp site went offline for some reason and I would like it to fail for those type of errors, but not because a file doesn't exist in ftp site itself.

I tried manipulating the maximumerrorcount to make it more than 1 but that didn't change anything.
I even looked online using this source https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2013/08/05/continue-package-execution-after-error-in-ssis/

To try event handler but that system variable propagate I cannot find it anywhere.

Is it possible that despite using failure constraint it still succeeds the package if the next code piece afterwards succeeds?

Comment: You can implement your logic in the script that you are executing, instead of implementing it in SSIS.